# Display a progress bar when uploading an image using the base64_encode method and jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image-processing, filereader

The main progress is like the following described.
Someone opens my site.
After that he/she makes ctrl+v and pastes the image but that is irrelevant.
Next the jquery is posting the base64_encoded image string to a php file and then there i am using explode to determine the extension and i'm generationg a random name for the image. 
How could i write a progress bar to this? 
Thanks for the help anyway.

```
$("html").pasteImageReader(function(results) {
var dataURL, filename;
filename = results.filename, dataURL = results.dataURL;
$.post("clipboardup.php", { img: dataURL }, function(data) {
$("#testing").html(data);
});
});
```

Comment: i would like to have an advise how coult i start to make something which would display the progress of the uploading of this base64 encoded string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways to provide upload progress monitoring of *normal* file uploads, such as the HTML5 [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/), Flash/Silverlight/etc based upload widgets like [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/), and the built-in [PHP file upload progress mechanism](http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php) (available in only the latest version or two).

However, none of these are built for *normal not-uploading-a-file* HTTP POST operations, which is the thing you're doing here.  In other words, there is no way to capture the data that you need to be captured.